# No logging platforms found in while using google flogger logging ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.flogger.backend.system.DefaultPlatform

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting the following error while using Google flogger with Spring boot application. I have already added the maven dependency so no compile time error.

```
public class FloggerLoggingExample {

    private static final FluentLogger logger = FluentLogger.forEnclosingClass();

    @Test
    public void test_flogger() {

        logger.atWarning().log("warning");

        logger.atInfo().log("info");

        logger.at(Level.SEVERE)
                .atMostEvery(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .log("SEVERE");

    }
}
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No logging platforms found:
com.google.common.flogger.backend.system.DefaultPlatform: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.flogger.backend.system.DefaultPlatform
```

Comment: plz add dependencies files(gradle, maven)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to say without taking a look at the pom.xml but I believe that `flogger-system-backend` is missing from your pom.xml. Try adding that.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.flogger</groupId>
    <artifactId>flogger-system-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.4</version>
</dependency>
```